# How to retrieve a JSON element from a JsonNode object as String using jackson?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm pretty new to Jackson and Spring-Boot. I'm trying to parse the JsonNode object to retrieve a nested property from the JsonNode object as a string.

This is for a spring-boot application where I POST a json file into an ArrayList of my class object and then reading a single array element into JsonNode object. I have tried to cast the JsonNode object to an ArrayNode and then store the parent property into it using

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.valueToTree(workflow);

ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) rootNode.get("metadata");
```

and then look for the required property in the arrayNode using

```
Iterator<JsonNode> arrayNodeIterator = arrayNode.elements();
while(arrayNodeIterator.hasNext()){
    JsonNode jsonNode = arrayNodeIterator.next();
    String str = jsonNode.get("name").asText();
}
```

Following is the json that I'm trying to read

```
{
    "metadata": {
      "name": "workflow-name"
    },
    "tasks": []
}
```

However, i'm getting following error on GET requests.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode cannot be cast to class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode and com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode are in unnamed module of loader '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the above JSON `metadata` is `JSONObject`  it is not `ArrayNode`

1) get the `metadata` as `JsonNode`

```
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.valueToTree(workflow);

JsonNode  metaNode = rootNode.get("metadata");
```

2) Now get the `name`

```
System.out.println(metaNode.get("name").textValue());
```

3) `tasks` is `ArrayNode` so get the `tasks` as `Array`

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) rootNode.get("tasks");
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this example...
>   for more information check here https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-to-jsonnode

```
 String jsonString = "{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

    // When
    JsonNode jsonNode1 = actualObj.get("k1");
    assertThat(jsonNode1.textValue(), equalTo("v1"));
```